# css multi-column that fills in a row

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I have a multi column layout that works very well. The layout publishes, let's say pictures, in a tiled format. However, I want it to be published based on time. I can do that in my query to pull data based on last modified time. But, the list is ordered by column1 and then column2 and so on.

```
A1 | B1 | C1 | D1

A2 | B2 | C2 | D2

A3 | B3 | C3 | D3
```

But I want it to look like

```
A1 | A2 | A3 | B1

B2 | B3 | C1 | C2

C3 | D1 | D2 | D3
```

and so on. How do I get this row effect on a multi-column? 
If I don't use multi-column I can get this effect, but then it is not responsive on smaller screens. Is there a easier way to make the multi-column behave like what I want or do I have to handle then separate for each device size?

Comment: Try to learn how to use [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) it can help you do that

Comment: Can you show an example of the HTML structure you have and the CSS styling it?

Comment: how about using a row layout instead of column?

Comment: I did use the row layout with flex box. It will still leave space if the flex items are not of same height. see example below (w/o flex box, but similar effect I get with flex box too).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could achieve that very easily using a CSS `float: left` layout instead of columns.  Here's an example of what it would look like:

```css
.flex-c {
    display: block;
    height: 450px;
    width: auto;
}

.flex-i {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="flex-c">
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
        <div class="flex-i"></div>
    </div>
```

This method works on all modern browsers and is totally mobile friendly.

Comment: as you can see in my code above, I am using float:left. Am I missing something?

Comment: What code?  Please make a JSFIDDLE and post the link in a comment.